# How to Set a state of parent component from child component in react js

Tags: reactjs

```
 how do i  change the state of parent in child component
I'm trying to create a popover in react 

Parent component

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          status: false,
          anchorEl: null
        };
      }

      showpop = () => {


        this.setState({ status: !this.state.status });
      };


    render() {
        return (

            <React.Fragment>
              <p id="popup" onClick={this.showpop}>
                Click me
              </p>
              {this.state.status ? (
                <Popup status={this.state.status}>test</Popup>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
      }
    }
```

i just passed the state of status to popover component .
This is the child component

```
export default class popup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      popupStatus: false
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.handleclick, false);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleclick, false);
  }


  handleclick = e => {
    if (this.node.contains(e.target)) {
      return;
    } else {
```

//here what to do?

```
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Mainbox
          status={this.props.status}
          ref={node => {
            this.node = node;
          }}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </Mainbox>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

In the handleclick function else part ,
i tried these
I change the node style display to none but in the window need two clicks to show a popover

you can see the Mainbox component in child  is created using styed components library

is there any way to hide the elemet and change the parent state?

Comment: You can pass a method that updates state as a prop to a child and call it from there.

Comment: please explain me in have tried to pass the method but how to change state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass a method reference to child:

```
<Popup status={this.state.status} showpop={this.showpop}>test</Popup>

  handleclick = e => {
    if (this.node.contains(e.target)) {
      return;
    } else {
      this.props.showpop()
    }
```